# Send mail body with Robocopy Summary in powershell

Tags: powershell, email, robocopy

I am using powershell to send mail with Robocopy Summary from sheduled task.

Below is the powershell version details

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.15063.502
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.15063.502
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

My script is below,

```
$pw = Get-Content .\bumblebee.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xyz\abc", $pw
$cont = gc C:\Users\Vinod_DMSE\Desktop\Bat\backup_log_20170816.log -last 12 |%{"$_ <br/>"}|out-String
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.xyz.com -to "abc@xyc.com" -Credential $cred -from "backupkr.alert@xyz.com" -Subject " Backup Alert" -BodyAsHtml $cont"
```

This works,

But when I'm getting the mail body with text alignment issues.

Below is the output

[image]

Is it possible to get output as in powershell with more aligned.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: use format-table and see `gc C:\Users\Vinod_DMSE\Desktop\Bat\backup_log_20170816.log -last 12 |%{"$_ <br/>"}|Format-Table| out-String`

Comment: No Luck Still same.

Comment: `-BodyAsHtml "<pre>$(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.log')</pre>"`. Otherwise you need to parse the log content and transform it to proper HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and help from @BenH, I have finalized my script. 
I am sharing this since I couldn't find any direct solution and direct way to send summary of robocopy. This method is very direct one any newbie can use it.

Please see my below main script which backups files from server

```
::Backup Bat file Created By Vinod Amarathunga 2017-08-11 V 3.0 Improved
::Please do not change anything
@echo off
::Login to the server
NET USE \\server IP\IPC$ /u:server IP\username password
::Backup 
ROBOCOPY "\\server IP\c\Program Files (x86)\source" /S E:\Backup\Backup_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% /unilog+:"E:\Log\backup_log_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.log"
::End the session 
NET USE \\server IP\IPC$ /D
::Archive Backup
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r E:\TMS_Auto_Backup\Zip\Zip_Backup_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.rar E:\TMS_Auto_Backup\Backup\Backup_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
forfiles /p E:\Backup /s /m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @path"
::Call mail script
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "C:\mail.ps1" 
pause
```

This script will delete files older than 7 days.
If you want you can comment or remove below line,

```
forfiles /p E:\TMS_Auto_Backup\Backup /s /m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

For archiving the backup I have used WinRar.

For mailing the robocopy summary I have written a another script from powershell
From main script, below line will called to run for sending mail

```
 powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "C:\mail.ps1"
```

Below is the mail script,

```
#Poweshell V 1.0 Script created by Vinod Amarathunga V3.0 Improved
$pw = Get-Content .\bumblebee.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user name", $pw 
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
$cont = "<font face='monospace'>$(Get-Content C:\Bat\backup_log_$date.log -last 12 | ForEach-Object {"$($_ -replace '\s','&nbsp;') <br/>"})</font>"
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mail.xyz.com -to "abc@xyz.com" -Credential $cred -from "backup.alert@xyz.com" -Subject "Backup Summary" -BodyAsHtml "$cont"
```

Below line will help to identify the log in given date,

```
 $cont = "<font face='monospace'>$(Get-Content C:\Bat\backup_log_$date.log -last 12 | ForEach-Object {"$($_ -replace '\s','&nbsp;') <br/>"})</font>"
```

For this date should be yyyymmdd format, this formatting date is must,

```
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
```

After scheduled[image] task executed I am getting above mail to my mailbox,

There is more resources available on internet, But I think this is the most direct method so far.

For accessing my mail account, it require to have user name and passowrd.
Powershell doesn't allow plain passwords Below link will helped me to understand how to use encrypted passwords

https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/

Answer (score 3):

As Ansgar alludes to, this issue is because of how HTML handles spaces. [Multiple spaces normally created by the spacebar, the tab key and return key are all ignored when you write code. HTML just interprets them all as whitespace between words, and displays a single space.](http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML)

So the two possible solutions are either to use the [`<pre>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag, which stands for preformatted text. In the context of your script would look like this:

```
$cont = "<pre>$(Get-Content C:\Users\Vinod_DMSE\Desktop\Bat\backup_log_20170816.log -last 12 | ForEach-Object {"$_ <br/>"})</pre>"
```

Otherwise you could replace your regular spaces with [Non-breaking spaces](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

```
$cont = "$(Get-Content C:\temp\rblog.txt  -last 12 | ForEach-Object {"$($_ -replace '\s','&nbsp;') <br/>"})"
```

Also another issue can be using a font with uneven character widths. Using the [`<font>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) tag with a font family where each character is the same width will help the text line up better.

```
$cont = "<font face='monospace'>$(Get-Content C:\temp\rblog.txt -last 12 | ForEach-Object {"$($_ -replace '\s','&nbsp;') <br/>"})</font>"
```

Comment: A "font with uneven character widths" is usually called a "proportional font". ;) BTW, I wouldn't recommend replacing spaces with non-breaking spaces. If you're going that route it's better to go all the way and parse the table section into an actual HTML table.

Comment: just what i needed